# How should I extend the drywall around a shower remodel?

Tags: bathroom, drywall

After removing a fiberglass tub unit and replacing it with a four piece shower unit, is it best to just piece in the drywall from where you cut out the unit or remove the drywall up to the ceiling and put in a solid piece?  More specifically, from the top of the shower wall to the ceiling there is about a 22" area (including the shower wall flange). The space of the cut out is 5" (including the shower wall flange). There is a 6" cut out down the sides (including the flange).  The ceiling height is 8'.

Comment: It would probably be helpful to post a picture. If your rep is too low, just post a link and someone will embed it.

Answer (score 1):

It's really up to you; there are pros and cons to either choice. Piecing in would be easier and quicker, but then you'd have a butt joint all around the shower to feather out. Tearing the rest of the drywall into the corners would look nicer (no butt joints), but would be plenty more work.